# How to check linearity in binary logistic regression with many covariates having 0 as a value

Tags: regression, logistic, logit

I'm trying to check linearity in my binary logistic regression. According to my handbook (*Discovering Statistics Using SPSS*, by Andy Fields: ch.19.8.1) this should be done by adding var*log(var) to the model and check for significance.

Many of my covariates however are binary variables which can be 0 or 1. Doing log(0) doesn't give an outcome which results in a lot of missing values when recoding the data. Now only 8% of my variables is used in the regression and I don't get the desired results. How do I do this check on my data where lots of values are 0?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is no problem. You are quite correct that this method can't be applied given zeros as data points, but there is a deeper issue.

Setting aside logistic regression, imagine that you are plotting any response on the $y$ axis against a covariate with just two distinct values on the $x$ axis. 
In your case the values are 0 and 1, but that doesn't affect the explanation I am going to give. Any transformation that I can apply that changes those two distinct values to two distinct values (whether the same or different) will not affect the linearity of the relation on the graph. At most, I might flip the values around (exchange smaller and larger) and then my relation will change sign (positive to negative, or *vice versa*). But there's no scope to play with a non-linear version of the covariate as an alternative. Using a logit link doesn't affect this: any transformation of a binary covariate just changes coefficients given different measurements, but it can't affect goodness of fit.

So, not being able to apply this device to binary covariates scored $(0, 1)$ is not a problem. It doesn't apply even in principle.

In general, it certainly can't work with variables that are ever negative or zero. In general also, you need at least three distinct values of a covariate for working on a transformed scale ever to be different.

I don't have access to the book by Field [N.B.] to check his rationale and whether he mentions any qualifications.

N.B.: What I call "distinct" values are sometimes called "unique" values. I don't follow that usage. Although language is always shifting, the term "unique" is best reserved in my view for values that occur precisely once.

Comment: Very well said.  Speaking in general, many statisticians are concerned about what kind of statistical principles are being taught by SPSS, and I would recommend that statistical training not come from an SPSS manual but rather from accepted textbooks and good teachers.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I agree with what you say, but I don't know what the precise relation is between Field's books and SPSS beyond the fact that this one is centred on using SPSS. I don't use SPSS at all.

Comment: I may have prematurely judged Field's book but from this one piece of advice I have worries.  SPSS in general does not often enough instill good statistical practice because of its choice of defaults in data analysis and statistical modeling.  For example, I see SPSS users (and to slightly less extent SAS users) assuming linearity more often than R and Stata users.

Comment: My guess would be the same, but I don't have any hard data. But to be fair this thread arises from an awareness that linearity should be checked, not assumed.